# Large Pages on IIS + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am getting some trouble with a ASP.NET MVC + IIS 7.5 page. I have a really extensive page that sometimes exceeds 15.0MB uncompressed and 1.5MB compressed.

When it happens, it looks like connection never ends. The loading icon stays forever and if I see at Developer Tools, the connection is pending, despite the entire HTML is received.

It happens at Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, so I think the problem is ASP.NET or IIS.

Do I need to do something special to handle such a pages?

Comment: 15MB?! May I ask how?

Comment: You need to ask yourself, do I need to throw 15MB to the user. Can't you serve the data on demand?

Comment: Actually not. The user wants to see all published files, so we have a lot of files

Comment: Does it have to be in one request and one file?

Comment: Its the main page in this project. The user need to work as fast as possible after the page is loaded, including client-side filters

Comment: I don't know what you expect the answer to be with this. You can't force Niagara falls through a hose pipe.

Comment: If I save the HTML to a static file, it works, so ASP.NET should be the problem

Comment: Don't do that! Break up the request, there's no way one human needs 15mb of data all at once.

Comment: Maybe it isn't the html that fails but some other resource. You see that from firebug. It has a feature where on the net tab it displays all external resources and how much time it takes to load them. Until it loads it shows a rotating gif

Comment: I am using it, Firebug at FF, Chrome Dev Tools and IE Dev Tools

Answer (score 5):

15MB is going to be horribly slow and unresponsive - not something your users want - however much they want to "see all published files".

I would introduce, for example, paging into your webpage so not all the files are downloaded at once.

However, if you really want a 15MB page, you may find the [limits config](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the entire HTML was provably received. How could IIS or ASP.NET be the problem then? Once the content is sent they are out of the loop.

The browser is probably the problem.

Comment: So you are saying that the HTML was not received by Fiddler? What do you mean by "despite the entire HTML is received"? Break with the debugger to see where the server is "hanging" (spending its CPU time).

Comment: If I open View Source, I can see the whole page, including the end </html> but the browser keep waiting, like a end signal is missing. After some minutes chrome shows at console that failed to load page

Comment: Ok so the server has sent all HTML and is correct. Do you agree? You probably have some blocking element on the page, like a script tag in the head that is hanging. I suggest you ask a new question where you give more information about what the browser is doing. You can post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting [Response.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526001%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to `false`.

> The Buffer property indicates whether to buffer page output. When page output is buffered, the server does not send a response to the client until all of the server scripts on the current page have been processed, or until the Flush or End method is called.

By default, `Response.Buffer` is set to `true`, so output will be buffered.  Perhaps by feeding the response to the client as it comes the browsers will behave as you need them to.

You do need to set the value of `Response.Buffer` *before* any output is sent to the browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try IIS compression?

```
IIS provides the following compression options:

Static files only

Dynamic application responses only

Both static files and dynamic application responses
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I am compacting, compacted page is 1mb

Comment: Can you post the sample page somewhere?